Error in DOCPLEX cp while using callback & blackbox
I am trying to use a code using a blackbox function in docplex cp. I also need to export information anytime the solver finds a solution, so I am using the callback functionality.
However, while doing so, I end up in an error in case I use several Workers. The error is the following one:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx/src/models/callback_test.py", line 350, in <module>
  File "xxx/src/models/callback_test.py", line 340, in main
    print("No solution found")
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/scheduling/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docplex/cp/model.py", line 1289, in solve
    msol = solver.solve()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/scheduling/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docplex/cp/solver/solver.py", line 714, in solve
    raise e
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/scheduling/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docplex/cp/solver/solver.py", line 707, in solve
    msol = self.agent.solve()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/scheduling/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docplex/cp/solver/solver_local.py", line 213, in solve
    jsol = self._wait_json_result(EVT_SOLVE_RESULT)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/scheduling/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docplex/cp/solver/solver_local.py", line 572, in _wait_json_result
    data = self._wait_event(evt)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/scheduling/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docplex/cp/solver/solver_local.py", line 477, in _wait_event
    assert evt == EVT_CALLBACK_DATA
AssertionError

Issue seems to come from there (docplex code):
elif evt == EVT_CALLBACK_EVENT:
            # First read the callback event
            event = data
            # Read event data in next message
            evt, data = self._read_message()
            assert evt == EVT_CALLBACK_DATA
            res = self._create_result_object(CpoSolveResult, data)
            self.solver._notify_callback_event(event, res)

I have an event callback, however, the next message is a blackbox event, not a callback data event.
This only happens if Workers > 1, so I guess this is a multiprocessing issue.
To reproduce this, I just added this code into the sched_jobshop_blackbox.py code, right before the solve:
 class MyCallback(CpoCallback):
        def invoke(self, solver, event, jsol):
            # Get important elements
            obj_val = jsol.get_objective_values()
            obj_bnds = jsol.get_objective_bounds()
            obj_gaps = jsol.get_objective_gaps()
            solvests = jsol.get_solve_status()
            srchsts = jsol.get_search_status()
            # allvars = jsol.get_solution().get_all_var_solutions() if jsol.is_solution() else None
            solve_time = jsol.get_info("SolveTime")
            memory = jsol.get_info("MemoryUsage")
            print(
                "CALLBACK: {}: {}, {}, objective: {} bounds: {}, gaps: {}, time: {}, memory: {}".format(
                    event,
                    solvests,
                    srchsts,
                    obj_val,
                    obj_bnds,
                    obj_gaps,
                    solve_time,
                    memory,
                )
            )

    mdl.add_solver_callback(MyCallback())

Knowing my need is "only" to be able to extract the gaps & current objective value while the solver is producing a solution, how can I do it ?
Thanks for your help.

I somehow solved my issue using a custom made listener. Don't know if this is the correct way of doing it, but seems to do what I need without crashing

I confirm this is a bug ,it will be fixed in the next delivery. Listeners are ok, or keeping callbacks with only one worker. Thanks for reporting.
